# How should I handle implicit transactions for a SQL Server stored procedure being called from an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I am using a database link to call a SQL Server stored procedure from an Oracle database. After the stored procedure completes, the implicit transaction remains open. The Oracle documentation makes note of this here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/gateways.112/e12069/ch3.htm#insertedID8 and states,

> "The gateway supports the ANSI-standard implicit transactions. SQL Server stored procedures must be written for this mode."

Should I take this to mean that the SQL Server stored procedure should include an unmatched COMMIT statement at some point within the procedure? Is this preferable to requiring the caller to finish with an explicit COMMIT statement from the calling side (i.e. could the latter approach lead to orphaned distributed transactions)?

Answer (score 0):

The article you referenced mentions that:

> "Running implicit transactions allows the gateway to extend the Oracle two-phase commit protection to transactions updating Oracle and SQL Server databases".

The "two-phase commit protection" means that if you have a transaction open in your Oracle connection, then even if the SQL Server proc calls "commit", the Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server leaves that transaction open on the SQL Server side until the transaction running on the Oracle side is committed (or rolled back).  If a commits occurs in the originating transaction (the transaction started within Oracle) then the corresponding updates to the SQL Server should be committed, and likewise for rollbacks.  So basically, before Oracle executes your procedure, it calls BEGIN TRANSACTION on the SQL Server side, then calls the execute for the procedure, then does anything else it needs to in the rest of the transaction (could be updates on the Oracle side OR the SQL Server side), and then only when COMMIT is called from the Oracle side will the gateway send the commit command back to SQL Server.

So the later option, requiring the caller (Oracle) to finish with an explicit COMMIT, is required.

If you added an unmatched "commit" within the SQL Server procedure, then SQL Server would likely throw the following error:

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure YOUR_PROC_NAME, Line 0
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

Also, your concern about connections that do not end gracefully (and could end up orphaned) is a valid concern, and good that you are thinking about that scenario. If the connection to SQL Server is broken, then SQL Server will rollback the open transactions at the time that the connection is closed.  Check out the "Errors during transaction processing" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

> If the client's network connection to an instance of the Database Engine is broken, any outstanding transactions for the connection are rolled back when the network notifies the instance of the break. If the client application fails or if the client computer goes down or is restarted, this also breaks the connection, and the instance of the Database Engine rolls back any outstanding connections when the network notifies it of the break. If the client logs off the application, any outstanding transactions are rolled back.

If for some reason, the Oracle Database Gateway would leave open a connection from a distributed transaction after an error occurs without explicitly committing or rolling back, then you could run into transactions that remain open, but I would not expect that to happen because that would defeat the purpose of a distributed transaction.

Comment: I've tried both options and verified that they both work. My concern is that if the Oracle code opens a transaction, acquires some resources, and then the connection ends ungracefully, those resources can remain locked for some time. The only way I can make sure that the resources are released is to commit the transaction on the SQL Server side, but it doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Comment: Using an un-matched `COMMIT` in the SQL proc worked?  That is surprising...  Is the proc structured something like `CREATE PROC myProc  BEGIN   ...some DML operations here...  COMMIT /*with no explicit BEGIN TRAN?*/ END` ?